# Same Header File for both DLL and Static Library

Tags: c++, windows

So the common (at least VS 2005 states) way to define exports/imports for a DLL is:

```
#ifdef MY_EXPORTS
#define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define MY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

class MY_API MyClass {
    ...
};
```

This works great if I'm just building my code as a DLL. However, I want to have the option of using a static library OR a DLL. Now one obvious (but terrible) solution, is to copy all the code, removing the DLL 'MY_API' defines. Now what would seem a much better approach is a command line switch to either define, or not define the DLL stuff. However in the case of a static library what should 'MY_API' be?

```
#ifdef DLL_CONFIG
    #ifdef MY_EXPORTS
    #define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define MY_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define MY_API // What goes here?
#endif

class MY_API MyClass {
    ...
};
```

Now assuming that this can be done will there be issues when a user of the library includes the header files (ie. will they have to define 'DLL_CONFIG')?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Nothing.

Leave it as `#define MY_API` and all instances of MY_API will simply vanish.

You can add new build configurations, such as Debug - DLL and Release - DLL that mimic the others except they `#define DLL_CONFIG`.

To clone a configuration, get to the configuration manager (like the drop down of the Debug/Release list box), then under 'Active solution configuration' select new. You can now name it "Debug - DLL" and set `Copy Settings` to `Debug` and now that's left to do is define `DLL_CONFIG`.

To do this, go to project properties->configuration properties->C/C++->Preprocessor, and type `DLL_CONFIG` in there. You will also see that's where things like `NDEBUG` and `WIN32` are defined.

Like [haffax said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089828/same-header-file-for-both-dll-and-static-library/1089853#1089853), use project specific names. I would recommend something like:

```
#ifdef THEPROJECT_USE_DLL
    #ifdef THEPROJECT_BUILDING_PROJECT
        #define THEPROJECT_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define THEPROJECT_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define THEPROJECT_API
#endif
```

Now users of your DLL just `#define THEPROJECT_USE_DLL` if they are using the DLL version, just like your "- DLL" configurations have.

Answer (score 5):

Just define MY_API as empty. Like this:

```
#ifdef DLL_CONFIG
    #ifdef MY_EXPORTS
    #define MY_API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
    #define MY_API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define MY_API
#endif
```

In case of static linking no declspec is necessary.

Users of your library will have to define `DLL_CONFIG` if they want to use it as a dll or not define it if they want to use it as a static library.
There won't be any issues as is. This kind of configuration is done in many libraries.

Edit: Of course you shouldn't use the names `MY_EXPORTS` and `DLL_CONFIG` as such. Use project specific prefixes for all of your macros, so that there are no name clashes.

Answer (score 1):

Do nothing. No special calling convention is needed to link against a static library. The only thing you need to do, is to make sure that the linker links with your.lib.